# cardinality, set of values

Tags: probability, inequality

For any given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a \le b$, what is the cardinality $\left|[a,b] \cap c\mathbb{Z} \right|$ ?

I pick at random an element $a$ from the finite set $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. I denote $t$ and $c$ two integer constants such that $t<n,c<n$. What is the probability of intersection of $[a, a+t]$ with $c\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: That question has **nothing** to do with set theory.

Comment: OK, I've edited.

Comment: Is it simply the cardinality of that set? Yes $Y$ is the cardinality of the set. Besides we know that if we replaced $3X$ by an integer $X'$, $X'$ could take $Y$ consecutive values.

Comment: Thank you @user142526. Yes they have the same cardinality. I just wonder if we can bound this cardinality by $\frac{Y}{3}$ since $Y$ represent the number of solutions in the case there was not the factor $3$...

Comment: @user142526 In fact I was reasoning in such a way, with an example, imagine the solutions $3x \in \{3,4,5,6\}$ then $x$ is in $\{1,2\}$. It seems clearly that the cardinalities are different. Besides this example contradicts the fact that the number of solutions for $x$ is bounded by $Y/3$. So I'm looking for the correct bound... Maybe this is $\lceil Y/3 \rceil$.

Comment: @user142526 Thank you. Maybe it's preferable that I ask,  for any given $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, what is $\left|[a,b] \cap 3\mathbb{Z} \right|$.

Comment: Still not a set theory problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\leq b$. Then one observes $\left|[a,b]\cap 3\mathbb{Z}\right| = \left\lfloor\frac{b-a+1+\left((a+2)\bmod{3}\right)}{3}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: How do you obtain this result ? Why $(a+2)\mod 3$ ?

Comment: Note that additions of $3k$ to $b-a$ will contribute $k$ to the cardinality of the set, so all we really have to do is verify for $b-a\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Thank you but I don't really understand your argument.

Comment: For $b=a$, the segment intersects $3\mathbb{Z}$ iff $a=b\in 3\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, iff $(a+2)\bmod 3=2$. If $b=a+1$, the segment is disjoint from $3\mathbb{Z}$ iff $a\equiv 1\pmod 3$, meaning that the segment intersects with $3\mathbb{Z}$ iff $(a+2)\bmod 3>0$. If $b=a+2$, the segment always intersects $3\mathbb{Z}$ (at a single element). If $b=a+m+3k$, the segment intersects $3\mathbb{Z}$ at exactly $k$ additional elements than the segment $[a,a+m]$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for this explanation.

Comment: Is this formula valid by replacing the constant $3$ by any other constant ?

Comment: As long as we substitute $(a+2)\bmod 3$ for $(a-1)\bmod k$, then yes.

Comment: Thank you. So we have $\left|[a,b]\cap k\mathbb{Z}\right| = \left\lfloor\frac{b-a+1+\left((a-1)\bmod{k}\right)}{k}\right\rfloor$ ?

Comment: Yes, it appears so.